# How come Android Studio only provides Nexus phones in "Device in Editor" instead of Samsung?

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-mobile

How come Android Studio only provides Nexus phones in "Device in Editor" instead of Samsung?

I just downloaded Android Studio this week. Here's the phones available in "Device In Editor":

[image]

When I go to "Create New Virtual Device", again only Nexus Phones are available, no Samsung. What's going on?

[image]

Also, why is the PLAY STORE check only for the Nexus 5X and Nexus 5 devices. Why not any newer devices?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the devices in 'device in editor' is not to cover every existing phone. Rather, it is to offer a spectrum of various screen sizes, densities, ratios, etc. So it really does not matter what type of device it is, as long as there is a diverse set of devices and screens offered (which there is). As for the play store thing, I am not sure.

Comment: Are all the NEXUS device sizes that we're offered in Android Studio also the same sizes for all Samsung phones?

Comment: Nope. Don't get too caught up in the screen sizes. The Nexus and Pixel lineup provide a very capable selection of screen sizes. Much more than would be needed.

Comment: So as long as I use the various layouts provided, I shouldn't worry to much about screen sizes because the layouts will adjust to the various Android phone's sizes?

Comment: Yup... layouts should act fairly similar. Just make sure as you are building your app that it adapts well to different types of screens. Use the various layouts provided to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is because Google isn't Samsung.  Why aren't there LG configs in the Device Editor?  Or HTC?  Because there are thousands of devices and it would be impractical to manage, even if those OEMs provided the info. Fortunately, they don't need to be pre-defined in there because you can configure your own AVD with any resolution, memory config, etc, to create any device you need to emulate.  More or less.

Of course, there's more to it than just defining the right resolution, etc. Many OEMs, including Samsung, roll their own OS updates, so even if you configure an AVD to match the S7, it won't really be accurate because the emulator will be running stock 7.1.2 (for example) and not Samsung's own flavor of 7.1.2.  But it'll be close enough for design work and general testing.

Going back to Samsung specifically, they do provide device details and skins to help you configure the emulator to more or less match their devices. You can find info about it here:

http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/emulator-skin

As for the Play Store indicator, Google has a brief and fairly unsatisfying explanation:

> Notice that only some hardware profiles are indicated to include Play Store. This indicates that these profiles are fully CTS compliant and may use system images that include the Play Store app.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Comment: A Samsung is an Android phone just like the Nexus is. Both owned by Google so Google is Samsung. But anyways, the "device in editor" nexus devices, are their sizes exactly the same as the current Samsung sizes?

Comment: Samsung phones are absolutely not Google owned.  Samsung makes their own changes to Android and makes their own phones.

Comment: Nexus devices are designed by Google (although not generally manufactured by them).  Google is typically directly responsible for the Android versions that roll out to THOSE phones and they control Android Studio, so those devices are in Device Manager as general targets for testing the various Android versions.   HTC, Samsung, and many others all make their own phones and software modifications to standard Android. It's an open platform with tens of thousands of different devices.  Google is not in control of 99% of them.

Comment: And, no, the sizes, screen resolutions, memory vary a lot.  You can configure AVD to generally match any device but for non-Google devices you have to find those values yourself and create an AVD to match.  You don't have to pick one of the predefined options.  You can configure it any way you need to.

Comment: So developers making apps for all Android devices in order to create for Samsung they all create an AVD to match by configuring their own values for sizes, screen resolutions in "Create New Virtual Device"?

Comment: No, probably not. I rarely use anything besides a few of the provided options. You can't possibly test on everything. You aren't meant to.  Android is designed to be flexible. Android layouts should adjust for resolutions.  Android Studio will tell you if code doesn't work across your desired Android versions, etc.  The Developer Portal will tell you how many devices your app can potentially run on based on your min and target SDKs.

Comment: The app I work on supports Android 4.0 to 8.0, and that's over 12,000 different Android device models globally.  We have analytics reports that show there are literally hundreds of different screen resolutions in our user base.  You can't test it all.  Develope using a few AVDs from the list, probably for each major Android version you support.  Try a 6.0 emulator, try a 7.1.1 emulator.  If you own a phone, obviously test it on there.  But if you are designing the app properly, you don't need necessarily worry about a specific Samsung device or resolution.

Comment: If I were to use minimum SDK 4.1 yet the 4.0 provides Social API's, User profiles, Large Photos, does it mean I won't get this if I use SDK 4.1 minimum? Or does every new SDK also offer everything from the old ones plus their new ones?
So as long as I use the various layouts provided, I shouldn't worry about specific device screen sizes because layouts will adjust to that phone even if I don't have that phone under "Device In Editor"?

Comment: Yes, that is generally correct.  Take a look at this documentation about supporting multiple screen sizes.  It attempts to explain how you organize your graphic resources and layout files so that you can properly support phones vs tablets, etc.  It's not the easiest topic to grasp but as you work with the layout controls and the design view in Android Studio, you'll start to see how the controls can adjust.

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html